# How to clean parts under the hood

Tags: cleaning

Would you advise how should I clean the parts under the hood?

When I say "parts under the hood", I mean the parts in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: damp rag and elbow grease...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Battery should be cleaned with a solution of baking soda and water, the rest can be cleaned with soap and water solution.